# If $\frac{X_a}{X_a+Y_a}$ and $\frac{X_b}{X_b+Y_b}$ are correlated, what about $X_a+Y_a$ and $X_b+Y_b$

Tags: correlation

Suppose I have four normal random variables:$X_a$,$Y_a$,$X_b$,$Y_b$.

$X_a$ and $Y_a$ follow bivariate normal, $X_b$ and $Y_b$ also follow bivariate normal.

let $Z_a=\frac{X_a}{X_a+Y_a}$ , $Z_b=\frac{X_b}{X_b+Y_b}$ and 
$Z_a*Z_b=p$,
p is a known constant.

Can I calculate the correlation between $X_a+Y_a$ and $X_b+Y_b$

Comment: Do you have enough info to compute $E(X_aX_b)$? If so, then the covariance between $X_a+Y_a$ and $X_b+Y_b$ can be computed from $E(X_aX_b)/p-(E(X_a)+E(Y_a))(E(X_b)+E(Y_b))$. From there, you can compute the correlation.

Comment: I don't think so, but I see your point.